# Emgu.CV on VB.Net Slow PictureBox Image

Tags: vb.net, winforms, emgucv

Using Emgu.CV Version 2.2.1.1150

I'm trying to query frames and display on picture box and the code works well on desktop computer with a Microsoft LifeCam 720p Picturebox is smooth and fluid but when I try the program in a Windows 10 tablet (CHUWI HI10X) the image is lagging.

If I test the tablet camera in the Win10 camera app they work very well and the video is HD and smooth.

I updated the drivers of these cameras to check if it was that but no luck.

```
Public Class frmCamera
Dim imgFrame As Image(Of Bgr, Byte)
Dim vidCapture As Capture

Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    vidCapture = New Capture(1)
    vidCapture.QueryFrame()
    AddHandler Application.Idle, AddressOf AppIdle
End Sub

Public Sub AppIdle(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    imgFrame = vidCapture.QueryFrame().Resize(800, 600, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR)
    PictureBox1.Image = imgFrame.ToBitmap()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    frmMain.Show()
    RemoveHandler Application.Idle, AddressOf AppIdle
    vidCapture.Dispose()
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

I've tried multiple frame sizes and different interpolation types with no luck. Also changed from using a imageBoxFrameGrabber to PictureBox converting to Bitmap but still same results. Also tried using a Timer but that looks worse.

Thanks!

Edit:

Using a Timer my code ends up like this with no luck.

```
Public Class frmCamera
Dim imgFrame As Image(Of Bgr, Byte)
Dim vidCapture As Capture

Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Interval = Timer1.Interval
    RichTextBox1.Text = "Interval:" + Convert.ToString(Timer1.Interval)
    Timer1.Start()
    vidCapture = New Capture(1)
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    frmMain.Show()
    vidCapture.Dispose()
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    imgFrame = vidCapture.QueryFrame().Resize(800, 600, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR)
    ' PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
    PictureBox1.Image = imgFrame.ToBitmap()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timer1.Stop()
    Timer1.Interval = Timer1.Interval + 2
    RichTextBox1.Text = "Interval:" + Convert.ToString(Timer1.Interval)
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Timer1.Stop()
    Timer1.Interval = Timer1.Interval - 2
    RichTextBox1.Text = "Interval:" + Convert.ToString(Timer1.Interval)
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

End Class

Tried disposing the image in the picture box as suggested and end up with a:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

At the moment of dispose.

Thanks again Jimi!

Comment: Application.Idle is called too often when you invalidate UI elements, as setting a PictureBox.Image property (~20,000+ times per second). Use a Timer (so you can define/tune a frame rate). If the Timer didn't work as expected, post that code. Btw, `Image.ToBitmap()`should return a new object, so you should have `PictureBox1.Image?.Dispose() PictureBox1.Image = imgFrame.ToBitmap()`.

Comment: Edited the question to add the Timer code. Also note that the two buttons I capture the Timer Interval so I can go up and down and try different ones but have tried from 2 to 300 with no luck.

Comment: I didn't write `PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()`, I wrote `PictureBox1.Image?.Dispose()`. If you have an old version of the language, change it in `if PictureBox1.Image isnot nothing than PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()`. It's not clear what is the Timer.Interval set to, what the results are using this timer or what actual problem you have. Se the Interval around 50ms, go down to a minimum of 35ms.

Comment: Oh that question mark worked. But the frames are still displayed sort of laggy, trailing, slow. Don't know how else to describe it. It's just on the tablet camera though, if I try it on a webcam it works well. As for the Interval I set it to 20 and use the buttons to go up and down to see which interval works best but they all just don't work. Wish I could take a video to show you.

Comment: Update: It seems I had the wrong drivers for the camera and while the windows camera app seemed to work smoothly my EMGU.CV app did not. I installed original drivers and is now working well with the timer.